# abbr[title] | Facebook, Display the tool-tip {timestamp} always?

Tags: jquery, facebook, timestamp, tampermonkey, abbr

```
<abbr title="Sunday, January 01, 2017 at 12:12am" 
data-utime="0000000000" data-shorten="1" 
class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">
<span class="timestampContent" id="js_d">1 hr</span></abbr>
```

I found a script, but it no longer works. So, anyone here willing to share how this could be done?

```
document.addEventListener("load", DisplayTimestamp());

function DisplayTimestamp() {
    var i;

    if (document.getElementsByTagName && document.getElementsByTagName("abbr").length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("abbr").length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].innerHTML += " 
    (" + new Date(document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].title).toLocaleString() + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I have made progress despite not knowing javascript.

I've found that,

```
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr").title;
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].innerHTML;       
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].title;
```

Actually retrieves the title and outputs it in the console. Not sure what to do from here on out though.

Further progress and I've managed to get it to make a change on the actual page, from the console.

```
var i = 0;
var d = new Date(); 
var n = d.toLocaleString();
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].title;
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].innerHTML;       
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].title;
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].innerHTML = n;
```

I don't know what I would need to do to get to work in a script and always display the timestamp, I could probably make a button at this point though that when clicked shows the time stamp, and just build it in to a browser extension.

If I want it to display the actual day and month in word format,

```
var i = 0;
var n = document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].title.toLocaleString();
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].title;
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].title;
document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].innerHTML = n;
```

Further Progress:

```
(function DisplayTimestamp() {
    var i;
    var abbrs = document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")
    if (document.getElementsByTagName && abbrs.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < abbrs.length; i++) {
            abbrs[i].innerHTML += "(" + abbrs[i].title.toLocaleString() + ")";
            //console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("abbr")[i].title.toLocaleString())
        }
    }
})()
```

Comment: @JZersche You seem to be taking the comments the wrong way. **Answers do not belong in the body of the question.** It's quite simple. If you want to provide additional information that answers your question, it belongs in an answer below like the other one. Your question is reserved for the question only. If you want to mark your question solved, use the check mark next to an answer. Do not add "solved" to the title - that is inappropriate.

Comment: When people are searching google, it's helpful. My apologies for looking out for the less knowledgeable community. I'll be sure to keep all knowledge to myself in the future, and not include it in the main body.

Comment: No one is asking you to keep it to yourself, so please stop being so sour about this. We're asking you to put the knowledge in the *correct place*. There's a big button below that says "Answer Your Question" - please click it and type your answer into the box that appears. If you'd like to continue arguing about site policies, please go to [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I got yelled at for answering my own question before.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-utime` attribute to construct the date, so assuming `abbr` is the element reference:

```js
new Date(abbr.dataset.utime * 1000).toLocaleString()
```

However, since Facebook loads content dynamically it's better to use MutationObserver to process the posts added after the page has been loaded (also when scrolling). This will also help us make the timestamps appear without any delay by adding `@run-at document-start`:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     FB: full timestamps
// @match    *://www.facebook.com/*
// @run-at   document-start
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @require  https://greasyfork.org/scripts/12228/code/setMutationHandler.js
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle(
    '.full-timestamp { opacity: 0.5; }' +
    '.full-timestamp:hover { opacity: 1.0; }' +
    '.full-timestamp:before { content: " ("; }' +
    '.full-timestamp:after  { content: ")"; }'
);

// process the already loaded portion of the page if any
expandDates(document.querySelectorAll('abbr[data-utime]'));

// process the stuff added from now on
setMutationHandler(document, 'abbr[data-utime]', expandDates);

function expandDates(nodes) {
    for (var i = 0, abbr; (abbr = nodes[i++]); ) {
        if (abbr.querySelector('.full-timestamp')) {
            // already processed
            continue;
        }
        abbr.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span class="full-timestamp">' +
            new Date(abbr.dataset.utime * 1000).toLocaleString() + '</span>');
    }
}
```

The code is using simple MutationObserver wrapper [setMutationHandler](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/12228/).

Comment: Use [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) with options, you can find many examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767088/i-have-a-script-that-shows-fb-timestamps-at-exact-time-using-moment-js-but-one

For some reason, older posts show as being 3 hours behind. Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like timezone shift. Try `new Date(abbr.dataset.utime * 1000 + (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000)`

Comment: As you can see the difference is that part after `+` so go ahead. As for 12-hour format, I'd use toLocaleDateString that has a corresponding option (see the docs). I haven't used moment.js.

Comment: I have no idea. It's a topic for a new question anyway. Most likely already answered somewhere.

Comment: Or you can simply display the `title` attribute as is: `'<span class="full-timestamp">' + abbr.title + '</span>'`

Comment: Hahaha, Holy crap. Here is my solution.

        abbr.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span class="full-timestamp">' + (moment(new Date(abbr.dataset.utime * 1000)).format('dddd, M/DD/YYYY, []')) + '' +
            abbr.title.substr(27, abbr.title.substr.length+3).replace('at','') + ':' + (moment(new Date(abbr.dataset.utime * 1000)).format('ssA · [UTC]Z')) + '</span>') ;

Comment: Hey so today the script stopped working, wOxxOm, any idea why?

https://greasyfork.org/scripts/26738-fb-full-timestamps/code/FB:%20full%20timestamps.user.js

Here's the URL.

Thanks